# iframe with video (youtube and vimeo) have weird behavior in safari

Tags: javascript, html, video, iframe, safari

I have this unexpexted behavour in safari the link is a download link to a video (from discord):
https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/662237135688040449/699959637000192010/Untitled.mov

can someone explain why this is happning or how to fix it. This error happens on a mac with macOS Catalina version 10.15.3.